# The word "hart" meaning "glade"

Tags: etymology

I am told that the word *hart* was in the past a substantive (not only an adjective) with the meaning of "glade", like a "forest grade".
As an example: *Steinhart* had the meaning of "the glade of the stones".
Can you confirm or deny this?

Comment: Was ist ein `glade of stones`? Leo sagt `Lichtung` für glade - was soll eine Steinlichtung sein?

Comment: @downvoters please re-consider your downvotes. The question is on-topic, clearly written, and does show some research effort. Please [do not vote carelessly](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/422/does-careless-voting-or-non-voting-damage-this-site).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there used to be a noun [*"Hart"*, *"Hard"*, *"Hardt"* or *"Harz"*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH02765) used in the meaning of a forest, or a mountain grown with trees.

Today there are still remnants of this meaning in names of locations, regions or towns. The most known region being *"[Der Harz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harz_%28Mittelgebirge%29)"*, a mountain range in middle Germany.

This may also be the case for the then names of the village and the ruined castle *"[Steinhart](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgruine_Steinhart)"*,  Bavaria, but the common meaning of the composite adjective *"steinhart"* is (and presumably always was) *hard as stone*, which is not related to a forest.

Comment: I had to think of Hardthöhe immediately... that was one catchy name. I wonder why they never use it anymore

Comment: yeah - [Hardthöhe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardth%C3%B6he) is another nice example :)